# How do I address peer clients (points) in an Azure Point-To-Site VPN?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, azure

Essentially, I want every member of the point-to-site VPN to have a unique name which I can use to connect from any other member.

I understand that I can add a DNS server to the Point-to-site VPN configuration in Azure, but how do I designate, for each client (point) that connects, what its particular name is?